# Command Binding And The Backspace Key

Tags: c#, wpf, command

I need to bind a command to the Backspace key.  The command needs to be enabled when keyboard focus is in a textbox, which in turn is inside of the DataTemplate for an ItemsControl.  The following code doesn't seem to acknowledge that the backspace key is being depressed, and the CanExecute handler for the CommandBinding isn't getting called.  Is it possible to have a command fire in this situation using the Backspace key?  Any insight would be very much appreciated...

Here's all of the xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Content}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here's the corresponding code-behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public static RoutedCommand BackspaceCommand = new RoutedCommand();

        private List<SimpleString> myList;
        public List<SimpleString> MyList
        {
            get { return myList; }
            set { myList = value; }
        }

        public Window1()
        {
            myList = new List<SimpleString>();

            MyList.Add(new SimpleString("First string."));
            MyList.Add(new SimpleString("Second string."));
            MyList.Add(new SimpleString("Third string."));
            MyList.Add(new SimpleString("Fourth string."));

            InitializeComponent();

            KeyGesture BackspaceKG = new KeyGesture(Key.Back, ModifierKeys.None);
            InputBinding BackspaceIB = new InputBinding(BackspaceCommand, BackspaceKG);
            this.InputBindings.Add(BackspaceIB);
            CommandBinding BackspaceCB = new CommandBinding(BackspaceCommand);
            BackspaceCB.PreviewCanExecute +=
                new CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler(PreviewBackspaceCommandCanExecuteHandler);
            BackspaceCB.PreviewExecuted +=
                new ExecutedRoutedEventHandler(PreviewBackspaceCommandExecutedHandler);
            this.CommandBindings.Add(BackspaceCB);

            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void PreviewBackspaceCommandCanExecuteHandler(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Inside PreviewBackspaceCommandCanExecuteHandler");
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }

        private void PreviewBackspaceCommandExecutedHandler(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Inside PreviewBackspaceCommandExecutedHandler");
        }
    }

    public class SimpleString : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string content;
        public string Content
        {
            get { return content; }
            set
            {
                content = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Content");
            }
        }

        public SimpleString(string p_content)
        {
            Content = p_content;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Andrew

Comment: Hmmmm...admittedly without looking too closely at the details of your code, I am trying to figure out why you would bind a Commmand to the Backspace key while in a TextBox.  Doesn't that change the expected behavior of the TextBox for your users?  

I can't really think of another application where pressing Backspace in a TextBox doesn't just erase the previous character (or selected text).  I'd think hard about doing this, unless your Command is supposed to do something in addition to or to enhance the expected behavior.

Comment: Yes Wonko, that's exactly what I'm trying to do...

Comment: My primary source of confusion is that I don't understand why the event handlers for the tunneling events aren't getting called in the command binding.  After all, the input gesture for the backspace key was attached to the root element in the xaml...